# How to start a single background task when django server boots up?

Tags: python, django, background-process

I need to run a long running background task when the Django server is started. This task needs to run in an endless loop, or restarted at set intervals. I was looking at Threading, multi processing, django-background-tasks.

The problem with [django-background-tasks](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is that if I just declare my task in tasks.py, it inserts a new task each time the server is restarted. So after a while, I have hundreds of tasks running, while I only need a single one.

The problem with Threads and multi processing, is that these tasks are not triggered at all, unless I do `import tasks` in `views.py`. In that case, they get triggered all the time, for example, `python3 manage.py makemigrations` triggers the task. I only want to run the task when the server is started.

How can I achieve this?

This is what I have now. This keeps inserting new tasks each time I restart the server, resulting in hundreds of parallel tasks.

```
tasks.py

REPEAT = 60*15

@background()
def process_transactions():
  ...

process_transactions(repeat=REPEAT)
```

Comment: What is this task doing? When you deploy/restart I assume you would want this task to be restarted?

Comment: This does some transaction processing in the background once every 15 minutes, forever. Yes, I want the task to be restarted when I re-start the server.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with django-background-tasks. Celery is a fairly mature library for running asynchronous tasks and has "beat" for running tasks periodically https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

Comment: try putting it in a singleton.

Comment: or put it in ready() of apps.MyappConfig